# Insert query showing an error

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ora-01438

I created a table in oracle10g using following query......

```
CREATE TABLE  "MOBILELOCATION" 
("EMPLOYEEID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "PRESENTDATE" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "PRESENTTIME" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "LATITUDE" NUMBER(6,10) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "LONGITUDE" NUMBER(6,10) NOT NULL ENABLE)
```

Table was created successfully... but the problem is while iam trying to insert a row into the table it is showing the error

```
error ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

The query i used is ,

```
insert into mobilelocation values(12303,'30-10-2011','09:30',16.9876,82.3426);
```

Where i voilated the constraints?? Please explain any one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your columns `LATITUDE` and `LONGTITUDE` are defined rather strangely - `NUMBER(6,10)` says 6 for precision (total number of digits) and 10 for scale (number of digits to the right of the decimal point).

You either change them to `NUMBER(*)` or to `NUMBER (10, 6)` or `NUMBER(*,4)` or similar... the correct declaration is hard to guess but all mentioned would work with the sample data you provided...

For reference see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i16209